# Multiple API Get Requests in one function

Tags: api, flutter, dart, get, request

How can I do multiple API Get requests inside of one function when all of their responses have different types?
(Code reference please)
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class for return values or use map.

```dart
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getAPI(/*input parameters*/)async{
  var result1 = await http.get(Uri.parse('url1'));
  var result2 = await http.get(Uri.parse('url2'));
  var result3 = await http.get(Uri.parse('url3'));
  return {
    'result1': json.decode(result1.body),
    'result2': json.decode(result2.body),
    'result3': json.decode(result3.body),
  };
}

\\ use it
var result = await getAPI();
Map<String, dynamic> result1 = result['result1'];
```

Comment: `get`  method doesn't accept a String type, it should be `Uri.parse()` for example. To run multiple `get` sequentially is not recommended, you should use `Future.wait`

Comment: What does the v in `v["result1"]` mean? I assume it is just a typo?

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to copy past `result` variable, but my keyboard command key is corrupted, so just `v` typed. So sorry :)